# Age group for UX related research

Tags: research

I have a survey which is related to UX and I want to get user demography data from the survey. But I have not much idea about what are the age groups need to consider. In different places, it shows different age groups. As an example, some article says consider age groups like 9 - 19,20 - 34, 35- 50 etc. Some say 25 -34, 35 - 50, 50< . Is there any standard for age groups in UX design? Also, I cannot ask age as a direct number in because it is not much ethical.

Comment: I'm not aware of any standards. It's more about what users' goals, needs, context and prior experience are than their age.

Comment: Could you share more information about what the survey or the study is about? Then we can share ideas on how to demarcate the age groups.

Answer (score 1):

I found interesting reading the [great article](https://www.typeform.com/surveys/demographic-survey-questions/) from Typeform.
It's one way to think about this kind of demographical questions.

The other way is not to ask for a standard, but maybe ask yourself what represents the users in my case, for my project.

It also depend on the current status of your projects:

- do you already have a product?
- do you have actual statistics?
- do you have competitors?
- did you already build personae?

You need to better know your potential users by doing some initial research (competitor analysis, digging into Analytics, or whatsoever) to be able to build Personae or proto-personae that will maybe give you a first idea of typical age ranges.

If you have nothing at the moment, and you are doing first research, it's a bit tricky, and you might end up picking an arbitrary decision with ranges based on your idea of your future users. There is nothing bad about guessing, trying, testing and failing in our domain.

Another path to explore is trying to find qualitative criteria instead of age ranges. For instance, ask yourself why you are asking user's age? Do you really need it?
What if instead you ask for their experience with "this thing, or this thing"? Or the way the qualify a competitor process? To give you more insight on how they feel with what you're about to build.

Also, not directly related, but worth reading: [Age group dilemma in surveys](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/120466/age-group-dilemma-in-surveys)

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on the research and the hypothesis (assuming you have one, not all research requires a hypothesis).

As an example: let's say you group by decade (0-9,10-19,20-29 ...). This could be useful for some research, but for most UX research (talking about products or services) it is useless, because 10 or 11 year olds will be closer to those at the extreme of the 0-9 group (not to mention the difference between 0 and 9), while 18-19 year olds will be closer to 20.

This is a case where groups should be clustered based on **physical and psychological development**

Then you have grouping based on marketing premises (yes, the [baby boomers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baby_boomers), [generation X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_X), [generation Y](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennials).... *{add whatever label you fancy}*).

Another way is grouping by perceived age (do you consider yourself as --> teenager, young adult, adult, middle aged, senior)

Finally, a very easy and uncompromising way to research age groups is to allow the user to enter the age number. Just add a select field or a numeric field with numbers from 0 to 100 and that's it (of course you can limit the range to whatever you want)

## Bibliography

If you're looking for more advanced, (somehow dense) information, you could try the following resources

- **[Systems and methods for custom grouping of data](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6996569B1/en)**  *by Jeffrey A. Bedell, Xun Feng, William Hurwood et al*
- **[Systems and methods for improving web site user experience](https://patents.google.com/patent/US8352396B2/en)** *by George Forman,
  Evan R. Kirshenbaum*
- **[Using psychophysiological techniques to measure user experience with entertainment technologies](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01449290500331156)** by  Thomas W. Calvert, Mandryk,
  Regan L,